# Allowing last line in "amount" column of dataframe to be a plug value to solve rounding error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have the following dataframe:

```
       BILL_NO    DUE_DATE  AMOUNT
0   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
1   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
2   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
3   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
4   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
5   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
6   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
7   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
8   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
9   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
10  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
11  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
12  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
13  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
14  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
15  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
16  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
17  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
```

The amount column is the total of invoice #1000005848 ($715.17) divided by 18. But as you can see, if you add up the amount column it equals 715.14.

This is the code I used to get the amount column:

```
df['AMOUNT'] = round(invoice_amount/len(df['BILL_NO']), 2)
```

This is causing a rounding issue.

How can I get the last row of the amount column to be a "plug-in" to cover the rounding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about manually adjust the last item:

```
# assuming `AMOUNT` is the last column
df.iloc[-1,-1] += invoice_amount - df['AMOUNT'].sum()
```

Output:

```
       BILL_NO    DUE_DATE  AMOUNT
0   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
1   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
2   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
3   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
4   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
5   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
6   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
7   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
8   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
9   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
10  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
11  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
12  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
13  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
14  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
15  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
16  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
17  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.76
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `saferound`, even it is not only trim the last row

```
from iteround import saferound
df['AMOUNT'] = saferound(df['AMOUNT'],places=2)
df
Out[261]: 
       BILL_NO    DUE_DATE  AMOUNT
0   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.74
1   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.74
2   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.74
3   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
4   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
5   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
6   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
7   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
8   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
9   1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
10  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
11  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
12  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
13  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
14  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
15  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
16  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
17  1000005848  01/06/2021   39.73
```

Comment: This actually will work better going forward for what I’m doing. Thanks!